# How do I get the paging event working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I click on the page numbers nothing happens. I have my gridview in a user control.
 The breakpoint does not even work.

Is there something that I am missing?

Here is my gridview html:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
EmptyDataText="No records" GridLines="none" Width="100%" PageSize="1" AllowPaging="True" 
OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdData_SelectedIndexChanged" > <Columns>  </Columns>  
<HeaderStyle CssClass="titleRow" /> <RowStyle CssClass="itemRow" /> </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
   public void grdData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{// actions here }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public void FillGrid()
{
//here your grid view binding code
}

public void grdData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
grdData.PageIndex=e.NewPageIndex;
FillGrid();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying the break point is "not working" which, I'm assuming, means the compiler is not hitting the breakpoint, you can probably try cleaning the solution and rebuilding after closing all open instances of the browser which has this page opened.

Other way is to explicitly try wiring the event to the event handler in your page_load like

```
grdData.PageIndexChanging += new EventHandler(grdData_PageIndexChanging);
```

Hope this helps.